# openssl libs in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, libssl

as the title suggests, I'm struggling to make the inclusion of openssl libs in my xcode iOs project, such as:

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/ripemd.h>
```

if anyone knows a good way to do it, that would be more than appreciated.
I tried to add the

```
/usr/include/openssl
```

to my inclusion paths in the project configuration, but it didn't turned out to be a good solution.

So, I was asking myself if anybody knew how to deal with it

thx a ton!

-k-

Comment: Why not use the Apple supplied CommonCrypto libraries? ripemd is available from: opensource.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, using OpenSSL on iOS involved building OpenSSL from source for the iOS architectures (though I suppose finding pre-compiled libs would also work), then adding the OpenSSL header files and configuring the project's Header Search Paths appropriately. I used [this](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/) as a rough guide.

Just be sure you really need OpenSSL before you commit. There are lots of built-in crypto routines in Apple's CommonCrypto and Security frameworks.

Comment: yes, I also tried libcommonCrypto.dylib but it still complains that the libs could not be found. I was giving a look to the the A Tasty Pixel blog post, but I read in the comments that you expect some oddities by running the project in Xcode 4, anyways I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @holographix, yeah, linking with libcommonCrypto won't make SSL available. That lib is an alternative to using OpenSSL directly, not OpenSSL itself.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [ios-openssl](https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl), which worked very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded openssl from [OpenSSL.org](http://www.openssl.org/source/) (see the version marked "LATEST") and used [this iOS build procedure](http://www.cvursache.com/2013/08/13/How-To-Build-openssl-For-iOS/). So far all is going well for me, but I'm in early stages of this development. The reason I needed OpenSSL was to do on-device in-app purchase receipt validation (see this Apple page on [Validating Receipts Locally](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2)).